# SQL Server: problem with synonym per user created by a stored procedure

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, synonym

I've got several stored procedures (worker procs) which will be queried by a main stored proc called `Calc`. `Calc` creates a synonym called `S` of a table, which name is passed by a parameter.

The worker procs work with the synonym table.

Works for admin login.

**Problem**: If a user executes `Calc` the synonym will be `Domain/Username.S` and the worker which access `S` doesn't find `Domain/username.S`

If the admin created the synonym it is called `dbo.S` and workers work by only accessing `S`.

How can the worker stored procs access the synonym created by the user which called `Calc`?
So that X users can call `Calc` and operate on different tables `S` but use the same worker procs.

Thank you in advance, hopefully somebody can help me.

Environment: SQL Server 2008
Granted User Rights: Create Synonym

Comment: I SOLVED the problem with a non beautiful WORKAROUND.
The synonym table was removed and Calc gets now a tablename as parameter which is passed to the worker Procs. These will now use dynamic SQL to work on the passed table.
Its now that good as synonyms but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the schema prefix when creating calc, executing calc, creating S, and calling S. Or make sure that all of your users have access to the same default schema. But I prefer the former.

Comment: The schema prefix depends on the executing user of calc. So how could a worker proc know this prefix to call prefix.S ?

Comment: If you create dbo.Calc, then the user calls dbo.Calc. Are you saying you have multiple copies of Calc with different schema?

Comment: One copy of Calc which creates different copys of S.
User1: exec Calc -> user1.S is created worker should work on this
User2: exec Calc -> user2.S is created worker of Calc should work on this